# how to combine two similar view into one

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have two views, one is for tags, the other one is for categories. That is **tags** field has ManyToManyField, and **categories** has ForeginKey relationship with my **post** model. My two views are here:

```
def tag_posts(request, slug):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tags, slug=slug)
    posts = tag.post_set.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/cat_and_tag.html', {'posts': posts})    

def category_posts(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    posts = category.post_set.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/cat_and_tag.html', {'posts': posts})
```

I want this :

```
def new_view(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404([I want model name dynamic], slug=slug)
    posts = instance.post_set.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/cat_and_tag.html', {'posts': posts})
```

is there a way of combining these two views into one view? I read about **contenttypes** framework. is it possible to do what I want with this?

Comment: What do you want the combined view to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through some url rerouting magic. This is your view:

```
def new_view(request, type, slug):
    if type == 'tag':
        instance = get_object_or_404(Tags, slug=slug)
    elif type == 'category':
        instance = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    else:
        return Http404()
    posts = instance.post_set.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/cat_and_tag.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Then, in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^(?P<type>\w+)/(?P<slug>\d\w_+)$', 'project.views.project_edit', name='posts_by_type')
```

Now you can use the new URL in your template code like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'posts_by_type' 'tag' slug %}">...</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{% url 'posts_by_type' 'category' slug %}">...</a>
```